# How to mount one partition from an image file that contains multiple partitions on Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, loopback

The image file has a partition table, and it contains multiple partitions.

loopback devices might be a possibility.

Related threads:

- http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2005-01/7183.html
- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2005-01/msg00077.html
- ftp://ftp.hq.nasa.gov/pub/ig/ccd/enhanced_loopback/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let's say $IMAGE is set to the path to your image file.
You could write a small script by using

```
fdisk -u sectors -l $IMAGE
```

to get a list of partitions inside the image. And then use a sequence of

```
mount -o ro,loop,offset=$OFFSET -t auto $IMAGE /media/$DEST
```

Where offset is calculated means the info from fdisk (start sector * size of a sector in bytes) and $DEST a unique name for each of the partitions.

That's not directly the solution but I hope a pretty good indication on how to realize it. If you make the job once, you've some small nice beginning for some forensic toolkit!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: While this answer works, the the more recent kpartx answer is really better; it gives you a single command that makes all the partitions available.

Comment: While kpartx is a nice tool, it is not available on every system. Several embedded systems I work on don't have it natively and I need to mount partitions of disk images or even sub partitions of a partition.

Comment: example application of above answer for Raspibian images: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/13138/359

Comment: This is really no longer the best alternative, with losetup -P available.

Answer (score 92):

You might do it like this, without much hassle:

```
# kpartx -v -a logging-test.img 
add map loop0p1 (251:0): 0 497664 linear /dev/loop0 2048
add map loop0p2 (251:1): 0 66605058 linear /dev/loop0 501758
add map loop0p5 (251:2): 0 66605056 251:1 2
# ls /dev/mapper/
control  loop0p1  loop0p2  loop0p5
# mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/test
# mount  | grep test
/dev/mapper/loop0p1 on /mnt/test type ext2 (rw)
#
```

And to remove the loop device after you finished:

```
# kpartx -v -d logging-test.img
del devmap : loop0p2
del devmap : loop0p1
loop deleted : /dev/loop0
#
```

Comment: Should also mention -d for tearing the setup down.

Comment: To tear it down, you merely replace "-a" with "-d"; in the example here that would be kpartx -v -d logging-test.img

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer, because this works even if `modprobe loop` misses the `max_part=63` (or similar) parameter.

Comment: What about the block size? You cannot set the block size of the original device with this tool. If you run `fdisk` on the file it assumes 512. The partition table stores positions as block counts, so the block size does matter. In the answer by @jdehaan you can say `-o offset=$OFFSET,block=4096` if that is the case.

Comment: This is no longer the best alternative with losetup -P.

Comment: It woks fine on ubuntu 19.10 and a virtual box converted img file! Thanks!

Answer (score 71):

If you have util-linux v2.21 or higher, you can now do this with losetup. Use the `-P` (`--partscan`) option to read the partition table and create device nodes for each partition:

```
# losetup --show -f -P test.img
/dev/loop0

# ls /dev/loop0*
/dev/loop0
/dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p2

# mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/tmp
```

Comment: I used losetup from util-linux 2.22.2 successfully as described above (Mageia 3 package util-linux-2.22.2-5.mga3.src.rpm).

Comment: One thing I noticed, though, is that using root, instead of sudo, made a difference whether it worked or not.

Comment: For me, I see the different partitions under loop0 when I run `fdisk -l /dev/loop0`, such as `/dev/loop0p1`, but none of the partitions can be mounted.

Comment: Works for me on Fedora 24, util-linux 2.28.2

Comment: Finally, the real solution. Anyone having trouble with this is likely running an ancient distro and should fix that first!

Comment: I know this is 7 years old now, but it deserves more upvotes due to how long it took me to discover this solution!

Answer (score 11):

**`losetup -P` automation**

`losetup -P` is the best method starting in Ubuntu 16.04 as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15200862/895245 , here are functions to automate if further. Usage:

```
$ los my.img
/dev/loop0
/mnt/loop0p1
/mnt/loop0p2

$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
/whatever
/files
/youhave
/there

$ sudo losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                                                                      DIO
/dev/loop1         0      0         0  0 /full/path/to/my.img

$ # Cleanup.
$ losd 0
$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
$ ls /dev | grep loop0
loop0
```

Source:

```
los() (
  img="$1"
  dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P "$img")"
  echo "$dev"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    echo "$dst"
    sudo mkdir -p "$dst"
    sudo mount "$part" "$dst"
  done
)
losd() (
  dev="/dev/loop$1"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    sudo umount "$dst"
  done
  sudo losetup -d "$dev"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this question is aeons old, but just for the sako of completeness: [This here](http://varghese85-cs.blogspot.ch/2008/11/mouting-partitions-with-losetup.html) seems a lot easier to me.

Quote:

```
rmmod loop
modprobe loop max_part=63
losetup -f /path/to/your/disk/image.raw
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/path
```

Comment: This fails on Ubuntu 14.04 because the `loop` module is built-in so `rmmod` does not work. How to fix that: http://askubuntu.com/a/673257/52975

Answer (score 0):

Some more automation to the previous answers that were great.

To further simplify the task (which is needed if you do it often), you may use my script `mountimg` to do everything for you. Just get it from https://github.com/AlexanderAmelkin/mountimg
and use like this:

```
mountimg disk_image.img $PARTNO /mnt/mountpoint
```

You may as well specify filesystem type and any other additional mount options if you like:

```
mountimg disk_image.img $PARTNO /mnt/mountpoint -t vfat -o codepage=866,iocharset=utf-8
```

When you're done with the partition, simply `umount` it:

```
umount /mnt/mountpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Andrew Y's answer.

If you run into this error:

```
/dev/mapper/control: open failed: Permission denied
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
```

Then you just need to run the command again using sudo.

I know it's not much of an answer, but it might help those that are fairly new to linux.

Also as of right now, the solution still works just fine, and I'm running it on Kali linux 2023.1