# How to create a multi partition SD disk image without root privileges?

Tags: linux, image, embedded

Is it possible to create a complete SD image in linux without having root privileges (that is, no loopback mount)? I'm looking for a way to automate embedded system image creation. The image should include a specific partition structure and partitions formatted to FAT and ext2 populated with files from the build system.

Comment: Two ideas come to mind: one would be preconfiguring permission for a specific task, maybe using fuse.  Another would be to simulate mounting using the same idea as fakeroot - an LD_PRELOAD to replace the file handling functions, and instead route file operations on a selected directory through an unprivileged userspace filesystem implementation with the image being just an ordinary data file.  You might well end up needing the usual fakeroot capability too, to set desired permission bits on the files in the image.

Comment: @user1442554 I believe I've correctly answered the question. If you agree, would you please mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 9):

**Minimal runnable `sfdisk` + `mke2fs` example without `sudo`**

In this example, we will create, without `sudo` or `setsuid`, an image file that contains two ext2 partitions, each populated with files from a host directory.

We will then use `sudo losetup` just to mount the partitions to test that the Linux kernel can actually read them as explained at: [How to mount one partition from an image file that contains multiple partitions on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/how-to-mount-one-partition-from-an-image-file-that-contains-multiple-partitions/39675265#39675265)

For more details, see:

- `sfdisk`: deals with the partition table: https://superuser.com/questions/332252/how-to-create-and-format-a-partition-using-a-bash-script/1132834#1132834
- `mke2fs`: deals with EXT formatting of partitions: https://superuser.com/questions/605196/how-to-create-ext2-image-without-superuser-rights/1366762#1366762

The example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Input params.
root_dir_1=root1
root_dir_2=root2
partition_file_1=part1.ext2
partition_file_2=part2.ext2
partition_size_1_megs=32
partition_size_2_megs=32
img_file=img.img
block_size=512

# Calculated params.
mega="$(echo '2^20' | bc)"
partition_size_1=$(($partition_size_1_megs * $mega))
partition_size_2=$(($partition_size_2_megs * $mega))

# Create a test directory to convert to ext2.
mkdir -p "$root_dir_1"
echo content-1 > "${root_dir_1}/file-1"
mkdir -p "$root_dir_2"
echo content-2 > "${root_dir_2}/file-2"

# Create the 2 raw ext2 images.
rm -f "$partition_file_1"
mke2fs \
  -d "$root_dir_1" \
  -r 1 \
  -N 0 \
  -m 5 \
  -L '' \
  -O ^64bit \
  "$partition_file_1" \
  "${partition_size_1_megs}M" \
;
rm -f "$partition_file_2"
mke2fs \
  -d "$root_dir_2" \
  -r 1 \
  -N 0 \
  -m 5 \
  -L '' \
  -O ^64bit \
  "$partition_file_2" \
  "${partition_size_2_megs}M" \
;

# Default offset according to
part_table_offset=$((2**20))
cur_offset=0
bs=1024
dd if=/dev/zero of="$img_file" bs="$bs" count=$((($part_table_offset + $partition_size_1 + $partition_size_2)/$bs)) skip="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
printf "
type=83, size=$(($partition_size_1/$block_size))
type=83, size=$(($partition_size_2/$block_size))
" | sfdisk "$img_file"
cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $part_table_offset))
# TODO: can we prevent this and use mke2fs directly on the image at an offset?
# Tried -E offset= but could not get it to work.
dd if="$partition_file_1" of="$img_file" bs="$bs" seek="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $partition_size_1))
rm "$partition_file_1"
dd if="$partition_file_2" of="$img_file" bs="$bs" seek="$(($cur_offset/$bs))"
cur_offset=$(($cur_offset + $partition_size_2))
rm "$partition_file_2"

# Test the ext2 by mounting it with sudo.
# sudo is only used for testing, the image is completely ready at this point.

# losetup automation functions from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/how-to-mount-one-partition-from-an-image-file-that-contains-multiple-partitions/39675265#39675265
loop-mount-partitions() (
  set -e
  img="$1"
  dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P "$img")"
  echo "$dev" | sed -E 's/.*[^[:digit:]]([[:digit:]]+$)/\1/g'
  for part in "${dev}p"*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      # Single partition image.
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    echo "$dst" 1>&2
    sudo mkdir -p "$dst"
    sudo mount "$part" "$dst"
  done
)
loop-unmount-partitions() (
  set -e
  for loop_id in "$@"; do
    dev="/dev/loop${loop_id}"
    for part in "${dev}p"*; do
      if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
        part="${dev}"
      fi
      dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
      sudo umount "$dst"
    done
    sudo losetup -d "$dev"
  done
)

loop_id="$(loop-mount-partitions "$img_file")"
sudo cmp /mnt/loop0p1/file-1 "${root_dir_1}/file-1"
sudo cmp /mnt/loop0p2/file-2 "${root_dir_2}/file-2"
loop-unmount-partitions "$loop_id"
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/77dd7baa68dac3534a50f8a084f732f378113c59/mke2fs-multi.sh).

Answer (score 6):

you might want to look at
[genextfs](http://genext2fs.sourceforge.net/), that creates an ext2 filesystem in a regular file without any sort of mounting.

Comment: See also https://github.com/maximeh/buildroot/blob/master/fs/ext2/genext2fs.sh which generates ext3 as well, without `mount` or `sudo` or otherwise root privileges.

Comment: Original `genext2fs` was pretty dead back then IIRC, Debian even mentioned that specifically (I've revisited the topic in 2013 last time).

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and couldn't find a viable solution, so I wrote this utility that we've open-sourced [here](https://github.com/braincorp/partfs).

From the README:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.image bs=1M count=4
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4194304 bytes (4.2 MB, 4.0 MiB) copied, 0.00470867 s, 891 MB/s
$ parted --script disk.image \
    mktable msdos mkpart primary 2048s 100% set 1 boot on
$ mkdir mntdir
$ partfs -o dev=disk.image mntdir
$ mkfs.ext4 mntdir/p1
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Creating filesystem with 3072 1k blocks and 768 inodes

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (1024 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ fusermount -u mntdir
```

Comment: By using:
1. fdisk to create the partitions into a sparse file
2. partfs to access the created partitions individually
3. dd to copy ext4 files generated by build root
4. fallocate to repunch holes to make the file sparse again

I could achieve all the things I wanted as non-root, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to do the same thing. My first attempt used the loopback block device, but I have  found work-arounds to both steps that require loopback.

### Steps with loopback

Here's what I'm doing ( $1 is image file name, $2 is file size):

1. create zeroed disk image file with `dd if=/dev/zero of=$1 bs=512 count=$(($2/512))`
2. create partition table with `parted -s $1 mklabel msdos`
3. create partition with `parted -s $1 "mkpart primary 0% 100%"`
4. attach partition to loop `sudo losetup --find $1 --offset $OFFSET_TO_PARTITION_BYTES`
5. make file system with mkfs.ext4 with `mkfs.ext4 -I 128 -L BOOT -b 2048 -O ^has_journal /dev/loop0 $SIZE_IN_2048_BLOCKS`
6. mount /dev/loop0

The loopback is used because

- in step 4 & 5, mkfs doesn't have an offset option so losetup is used to solve that problem
- in step 6, mount allows the use of the operating systems ext4 driver

### Looback workarounds

Shitty work-around for step 4 & 5:

- xmount --in dd --out vdi disk.img mnt/
- vdfuse -f mnt/disk.vdi -r ./mnt2
- ./mnt2 will now have two files: EntireDisk, and Partition1
- point mkfs.ext4 at ./mnt2/Partition1

Work-around solution to step 6:

- follow all steps for step 5 work around
- use fuseext2 to mount ./mnt2/Partition1

### Caveat

Caveat: ext4 support is not advertised in their documentation, and attempts to mount come with a warning:

```
This is experimental code, opening rw a real file system could be
dangerous for your data. Please add "-o ro" if you want to open the file
system image in read-only mode, or "-o rw+" if you accept the risk to test
this module
```

#### Update

vdfuse should be able to mount a raw image without the help of xmount, but there is a bug which ignores the RAW option.

I tracked down and fixed the bug with a patch here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-ose/+bug/1019075

Comment: Have you find a way to make it works? It sounds it comes from years now, but looking at the bug it seems nothing have been done. Does it comes from the version of your tools?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing has been done. You can use my patch if you're willing to recompile the tool.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible with guestfish:

```
$ cat << END > extlinux.conf
> default linux
> timeout 0
>
> label linux
> kernel /vmlinuz
> append initrd=/initrd.img root=/dev/vda1 rw console=ttyS0
END
$ guestfish -N debian-unstable.img=disk:2G -- \
    part-disk /dev/sda mbr : \
    part-set-bootable /dev/sda 1 true : \
    mkfs ext2 /dev/sda1 : mount /dev/sda1 / : \
    tar-in debian-unstable.tar / : \
    extlinux / : \
    copy-in extlinux.conf /
```

The result will be `debian-unstable.img` with one ext2 partition on it, containing all files from the tarball `debian-unstable.tar` and the whole thing is made bootable with extlinux. You can verify the disk image using qemu.

Comment: guestfish is a good option. Worth noting that due to an Ubuntu bug, you have to first modify permissions on the kernel image so that QEMU can use it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046828/how-to-run-libguestfs-tools-tools-such-as-virt-make-fs-without-sudo

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible with these steps:

1. create disk-image file with dd(or truncate)
2. create partition[s] on/in it with fdisk(or parted)
3. get partition size, and create new image[s] with same size
4. mkfs.$fstype the image[s]
5. dd write back these images into disk-image

here's [my code](https://github.com/tcler/kiss-vm-ns/blob/master/utils/.deprecated/create-vdisk.sh):

```
create_vdiskn() {
local path=$1
local dsize=$2
local fstype=$3
local imghead=img-head-$$
local imgtail=img-tail-$$
local fn=${FUNCNAME[0]}

echo -e "\n[$fn:info] creating disk and partition"
dd if=/dev/null of=$path bs=1${dsize//[0-9]/} seek=${dsize//[^0-9]/}
printf "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw\n" | fdisk "$path"
partprobe "$path"

read pstart psize < <( LANG=C parted -s $path unit B print | sed 's/B//g' |
    awk -v P=1 '/^Number/{start=1;next}; start {if ($1==P) {print $2, $4}}' )
echo -e "\n[$fn:info] split disk head and partition($pstart:$psize)"
dd if=$path of=$imghead bs=${pstart} count=1
truncate --size=${psize} $imgtail

echo -e "\n[$fn:info] making fs($fstype)"
mkfs.$fstype $MKFS_OPT "$imgtail"

echo -e "\n[$fn:info] concat image-head and partition"
cat $imghead $imgtail >$path
rm -vf $imghead $imgtail
}
```