# How to script sfdisk or parted for multiple partitions?

Tags: bash, partitioning

For QA purposes I need to be able to partition a drive via a bash script up to 30 or more partitions for both RHEL and SLES.

I have attempted to do this in BASH with fdisk via a "here document" which works but as you can guess blows up in various steps. I assume this is because of timing of the input commands occurring at the wrong times and getting out of sync. 1 out of 10 times my script will work correctly.

I have looked at parted and sfdisk and don't really understand how to use these tools.

I have only ever used fdisk.

My issue is that with fdisk you can state something like "new partition +1gb" over and over and this works for me because in my script I don't need to keep track of prior partitions or remaining space or do any calculations. Every time I run this function this just makes an additional 1gb partition from any unused space.

Is there a way to use parted or sfdisk (or any other tool that would already be a part of these distros) so that I could script a loop from 1 to x operations without having to do this accounting of remaining space? Does anyone have any examples they could share?

### Update

Here is an example of one of my functions. At the start of the script we ask the user for the number of partitions to create, their size (this is static for all), and type of FS if any. This functions creates partition 1 thru 3 then a different function handles the extended (4th)  and another handles 5th to nn.

As I said before, this script is fully functional; my problem is that at times the commands being sent to fdisk seem to arrive at the wrong timing, which then breaks the entire script thereby breaking any automation.

So the commands are being sent like this:

```
n
p
1

+1M
w
```

I have been reading up on fdisk and have learned it is not suited well for scripting so what I am seeing is that when in script mode, fdisk might be asking for `p` my script already thinks it's time to send the `1`.

The thing about fdisk that worked for me is that after you specify the partition number it already **calculated the next free sector** so all I have to do at this point is send a blank line for my start and then the +1M for my total size. Parted and sfdisk don't appear to work this way from what I can tell and I am still very new at this to understand how to automate those tools at this time.

```
Create1to3Primary_Func() {
    Size=\+$partSize\MB
    for i in {1..3}
    do
        echo " this loop i= $i"
        echo "Creating Partition $i on $targetFull as $targetFull$i using Create1to3Primary_Func()"
        rm -f /tmp/myScript
        echo -e "n" >> /tmp/myScript
        echo -e "p" >> /tmp/myScript
        echo -e "$i" >> /tmp/myScript
        echo -e " " >> /tmp/myScript
        echo -e "$Size" >> /tmp/myScript
        echo -e "w" >> /tmp/myScript
        echo -e "EOF" >> /tmp/myScript
        fdisk $targetFull < /tmp/myScript
        echo "  sleeping Create1to3Primary_Func()"
        sleep 4s
        if [ "$RawOrFs" == "f" ]; then
            mkfsCMD="mkfs.$fsType"
            mkfsFullTarget="$targetFull$i"
            cmdline="$mkfsCMD $mkfsFullTarget -L  'Partition$i'"
            echo "Creating $fsType File System on $mkfsFullTarget"
            $cmdline
        fi
        void="/mnt/mymnt$i"
        if [ ! -d $void ] ; then
            echo "Creating Mount Point /mnt/mymnt$i"
            void="/mnt/mymnt$i"
            mkdir $void
        fi
        echo "Part Probe on  $targetFull "
        partprobe $targetFull ; sleep 4s
    done
}
```

Comment: show us your code. Impossible to diagnose this based on your current description. Good luck.

Answer (score 19):

Not sure to get what you really want, but you may be interested by the fact that `sfdisk` can dump a partition layout and use this layout to partition other disks. For instance:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > mydiskpartitionslayout
```

Then in your script (take care of course) you can specify

```
sfdisk /dev/sdx < mydiskpartitionslayout
```

Comment: Just make sure you are not using GPT with sfdisk. It is not supported combination.

Comment: Since  version 2.26 sfdisk supports GPT (and MBR (DOS),  SUN and SGI)

Comment: Just to update this answer, most distros now include `gdisk` and `sgdisk` which are GPT parallel utilities to`fdisk` and `sfdisk`. So this answer is still the best response, but if you want GPT partitions you should use the above command syntax using `gdisk` or `sgdisk` instead of `fdisk` or `sfdisk`.

Answer (score 8):

**sfdisk**

`sfdisk` is a Scripted version of `fdisk`

[It is part of `util-linux`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/disk-utils?h=stable/v2.27), just like `fdisk`, so availability should be the same.

A partition table with a single partition that takes the whole disk can be 
 created with:

```
echo 'type=83' | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdX
```

and more complex partition tables are explained below.

To generate an example script, get the setup of one of your disks:

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.sfdisk
```

Sample output on my Lenovo T430 Windows 7 / Ubuntu dual boot:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x7ddcbf7d
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=     3072000, type=7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=     3074048, size=   195430105, type=7
/dev/sda3 : start=   948099072, size=    28672000, type=7
/dev/sda4 : start=   198504446, size=   749594626, type=5
/dev/sda5 : start=   198504448, size=   618891264, type=83
/dev/sda6 : start=   940277760, size=     7821312, type=82
/dev/sda7 : start=   817397760, size=    61437952, type=83
/dev/sda8 : start=   878837760, size=    61437500, type=83
```

Once you have the script saved to a file, you can apply it to `sdX` with:

```
sudo sfdisk /dev/sdX < sda.sfdisk
```

For `sfdisk` input, you can just omit the device names, and use lines of type:

```
start=        2048, size=     3072000, type=7, bootable
```

They are just ignored if present, and the device name is taken from the command line argument.

Some explanations:

- header lines: all optional:

  - `label`: type of partition table. [`dos` (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is the old an widely supported one, [`gpt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) the new shiny thing.
  - `unit`: only `sector` is supported. 1 sector usually equals 512 bytes. Find with `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/hw_sector_size` See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/finding-the-sector-size-of-a-partition
  - `device`: informative only I think
- partition lines:

  - `start`: offset inside the disk at which the partition starts.

    `start` has very good defaults, and can often be ommited:

    - on the first line, `start` is 2048, i.e. 1Mb (2048 + 512), which is a sane default for disk compatibility
    - further `start` default to the first unallocated position
  - `size`: `man sfdisk` says: `The default value of size indicates "as much as possible"`. So to fill the disk with a single partition use: `/dev/sda : start=2048, type=83`
  - `type`: magic byte stored on the boot sector for each [partition entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PTE). Possible values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type On this example we observe:

    - `7` (`sda1`, `2` and `3`): filesystems that Windows supports. Preinstalled Windows stuff and Lenovo recovery partitions. `sudo blkid` labels help identify them.
    - `5` (`sda4`): extended primary partition, which will contain other logical partitions (because we can only have 4 primary partitions with MBR)
    - `83`(`sda5`, `7`, and `8`): partitions which Linux supports. For me one `home`, and two roots with different Ubuntu versions
    - `82` (`sd6`): swap

`fdisk` can also read `sfdisk` scripts with the `I` command, which "sources" them during an interactive `fdisk` session, allowing you further customization before writing the partition.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, `sfdisk` 2.27.1.

**Format and populate the partitions an image file without `sudo`**

This is a good way to learn to use `sfdisk` without blowing up your hard disks: [How to create a multi partition SD disk image without root privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949169/how-to-create-a-multi-partition-sd-disk-image-without-root-privileges/52850819#52850819)

Comment: With respect to the size field, it can be omitted for the last partition so as to fill the remaining disk space. As an example, if sda4 is the last partition, can use:
/dev/sda4 : start=  2664448, Id=83

Answer (score 1):

An approach I like (which I saw in [this article](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-run-fdisk-in-non-interactive-batch-mode.html)) is to "script" the fdisk input directly, since it's smarter than sfdisk about creating a partition "until the end of the disk" or "2 GB large". Example:

```
echo "d
1
d
2
d
3
n
p
1

+2G
n
p
2


w
" | fdisk /dev/sda
```

This script deletes up to 3 existing partitions, creates a 2 GB partition (e.g. swap) and then creates a partition that would extend over the remaining disk space.

In contrast, if a partition layout was created and used in sfdisk, the script would not cover the whole disk if more space was available.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
# initialize gpt disk
echo 'label: gpt' | sfdisk /dev/vda
```

or:

```
# create mbr ext4 partition mazimum size
echo 'type=83' | sfdisk /dev/vda
```

or:

```
# Named-fields format gpt
sfdisk /dev/vda << EOF
label: gpt
# comment: uuid == PARTUUID, 'uuid=X,' don’t have to specify it, then it will be generated randomly
start=, size= 100M, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, uuid=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111, name="EFI system partition"
start=, size= 650M, type=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC, uuid=22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222, name="Windows RE"
start=, size= 45G , type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333, name="Microsoft basic data"
EOF
sfdisk --dump /dev/vda
blkid | sort
```

or mbr:

```
# Named-fields format mbr
sfdisk /dev/vda << EOF
label: dos
label-id: 0xaaaaaaaa
# comment:
start=, size= 50M,  type= 7 , bootable
start=, size= 650M, type= 27
start=, size= 45G , type= 7
EOF
fdisk -l /dev/vda; echo
blkid | sort
```

Examples fields see from real working hdd:

```
sfdisk --dump /dev/vda
```

Answer (score -1):

Automating repetitive task is a norm in the life of automation and we need a method to automatically provide answers to these programs if we are to include them in our script.

This is where a program called “Expect” steps in to automate. For Red Hat based systems, execute the below command to install "Expect"

yum install expect

For Debian based or Ubuntu, execute the below command.

apt-get install expect

below is the expect script to create a partition /dev/sdc

---

## !/usr/bin/expect

log_file -a "/tmp/expect.log"

set timeout 600

spawn /sbin/fdisk /dev/sdc

expect "Command (m for help): " { send "n\r" }

expect "p   primary partition (1-4)"

expect "" { send "p\r" }

expect "Partition number (1-4): " { send "1\r" }

expect "First cylinder (1-133544, default 1): " { send "1\r" }

expect ": " { send "\r" }

expect "Command (m for help): " { send "w\r" }

interact