# How to load kernel from fat partition in u-boot under qemu ( arm versatile pb )

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, freebsd, qemu, u-boot

I have added to u-boot versatile pb config file located in include/configs/versatile.h this lines:

```
#define CONFIG_CMD_FAT
#define CONFIG_DOS_PARTITION           1
```

to add fatload command to u-boot. So I have fatload command suported.
And I'm starting u-boot this way:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel u-boot
```

Now question is how to pass to qemu file that contains fat filesystem with kernel ( im interested in booting FreeBSD kernel, but i think example with loading Linux could help me too ) and then load kernel and boot it under u-boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem here is that the versatilepb does not support SD/MMC cards in U-Boot, so you can't really.  If however you wanted to do this on another device that does support SD/MMC (like the vexpress-a9) you would do:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=sd.bin bs=1k count=$((64  * 1024))
$ fdisk ./sd.bin
... create a partition
```

Then read [loopback mounting individual partitions from within a file that contains a partition table on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/loopback-mounting-individual-partitions-from-within-a-file-that-contains-a-parti) for how to to use losetup to make that partition available, format it and then mount and copy data like it was a real SD card.  Then:

```
$ qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -kernel vexpress_ca9x4/u-boot  -nographic -sd sd.bin
```

And now the 'mmc' command will work with that sd.bin file.